# Definir height dinâmico para div com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Gostaria de um script que pegue minha `div` com a `class` master e defina `height: 100%` de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>*</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="master">
        <header>
        </header>
        <footer>        
        </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

css:

```
*{}
html {

}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**O elemento filho, nesse caso .master, tem sua width relacionada ao elemento pai, nesse caso o body.** Podemos, portanto, definir o atributo width de body como 100vw (Toda a largura da tela) para fazer com que ele preencha todo o espaçamento horizontal. Em seguida, devemos fazer com que a div.master preencha esse espaço, nesse caso podemos utilizar o mesmo atributo como 100% no elemento filho para que ele siga o elemento pai em toda a sua largura.

```
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      width: 100vw; 
    }

    .master {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha, acredito que não seja necessário utilizar js para isso.
Já tive problemas com isso antes... O caso é que o height 100% é referente ao elemento pai, que no caso, não tem height definido e 100% de nada é nada!

Faça isso no css:

```
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.master{height:100%;}
```

Veja se funciona...